# Saving svg generated in shiny

Tags: svg, shiny, htmltools

I am trying to save an `.svg` that I generate inside a shiny app using htmltools (MRE below). This requires adding the svg namespace to the svg tag with `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`. It renders fine inside the app, but when I open the generated file in a browser I get this error:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated
> with it. The document tree is shown below.

Looking in a text editor the code looks fine:

> `<svg xlmns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 100 100" height="100%">`

In Firefox, `xmlns:xlink` is missing completely from what's presented in the tree:

> `<svg xlmns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 100 100" height="100%">`

In Chromium, the `xmlns:xlink` is presented before `xlmns`:

> `<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlmns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 100 100" height="100%">`

I've edited the text file and typed the *exact* same line and then it renders correctly! I suspect it is something to do with the encoding of the `:` character. I've also tried using `gsub()` to add the `xmlns:xlink` inside the `downloadHandler()` rather than in the `tags$svg` but have the same error.

```
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    downloadButton("download")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("svgout")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  svg_pattern <- reactive({
    tagList(tags$svg(xlmns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 
                     `xmlns:xlink` = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", 
                     version="1.1",
                     viewbox = "0 0 100 100",
                     height = "100%",
                     tags$circle(cx = 50,
                                 cy = 50,
                                 r = 10,
                                 `stroke-width` = 1,
                                 stroke = "black")),
            )
  })
  
  output$svgout <- renderUI({
    svg_pattern()
  })
  
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){
      "your.svg"
    },
    content = function(file){
      write(as.character(svg_pattern()), file)
    }
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with Edge and it works without the `xmlns:xlink`, but this is `viewBox` and not `viewbox`:

```r
  svg_pattern <- reactive({
    tagList(tags$svg(xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
                     viewBox = "0 0 100 100",
                     tags$circle(cx = 50,
                                 cy = 50,
                                 r = 10,
                                 `stroke-width` = 1,
                                 stroke = "black")),
    )
  })
```

In fact, even without the `xmlns` you can visualize the file with a viewer such as Image Glass on Windows, but in a browser you'll only see the XML code.

Comment: That fixes the MRE but when I move it to the actual app l still get the same error... and I definitely need to open in a browser as the actual svg is animated

Comment: Now I realised that I used `xlmns` not `xmlns` Doh!